# How can I validate multiple action parameters with ValidationAttribute in ASP.NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Consider the following controller action signatures:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Whatever> Get(DateTime from, DateTime to)
```

Or

```
[HttpGet]
public Whatever Get(int amount, SomeUnit unit)
```

I'd like to be able to run a validation on parameters supplied by the caller. In both cases what passes as valid input in the first parameter depends on the value of second one.

So far I have failed to find an explanation or example of how this can be achieved with validation attributes in ASP.NET Core 3.0

I see that for example [CustomValidationAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute?view=netcore-3.1) allows using it on methods. I can give it a method that IsValid will delegate to and provide object and validation context:

```
IsValid(Object, ValidationContext)
```

I checked documentation of both IsValid and ValidationContext and I cannot find any hint on how would I access the parameters passed to the validated action.

While googling for hints I found an excerpt from "[Pro ASP.NET Web API](https://books.google.no/books?id=XWT9AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA405&dq=pro%20asp.net%20canonical&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi66Lro5bfnAhVs1qYKHVYSD1AQ6AEIQzAD#v=onepage&q=pro%20asp.net%20canonical&f=false)" HTTP Web Services in ASP.NET" where they implement something similar. The excerpt ends however before the code is shown and I don't have that book (didn't find a corresponding book but on ASP.NET Core).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CustomValidationAttribute` is used for properties and parameters. For an action validation you should write your own filter. Here is an example:

```
public class MyValidationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if(context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var dateFrom = (DateTime)context.ActionArguments["from"];
            var dateTo = (DateTime)context.ActionArguments["to"];

            if(dateFrom <= dateTo)
            {
                // continue the flow in pipeline
                return;
            }
        }

        context.Result = new BadRequestResult();
    }
}
```

And then you can use it in your controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[MyValidation]
public IEnumerable<Whatever> Get(DateTime from, DateTime to)
{
    // Here ModelState.IsValid is true
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I see this will work, but I was hoping asp.net core would offer a more elegant solution. You see, I already have ActionFilter (applied globally to all controllers) which checks if ModelState is not valid and then returns my custom error reponse with all the validation errors. With your approach, I am not sure how much control do I have over which action filter acts first. If there are already some validation errors on the model, and my error-returning filter would act first, I would return potentially incomplete number of validation errors to the caller.

Comment: @Emil you can set a filter's Order property

Comment: Is there any way to use existing validators? `[StringLength(1)]` etc?